# How to customise 2 simultaneous alerts in one pinescript for different timeframes

Tags: alert, pine-script

I am having 2 different indicators from trading view scripts. I want the first indicator to work on an hourly timeframe.

And once the buy or sell triggers in 1st indicator on 1 hr chart, I want the next indicator (the second one) to work on a 5 minute chart and then give me a buy or sell alert. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) function.

Below code requests the 1-hour SMA value which can work on any timeframe < 1 hour.

```
//@version=4
study(title="High Time Frame MA", overlay=true)
src = close, len = 9
out = sma(src, len)
out1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, '60', out)
plot(out1)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Actually security () function is the one i am stuck. The following condition is for 1 hr timeframe.       alertcondition(isbullish,title"bullish",message="bullish.caveat emptor.") How do i insert the security function.??

Comment: Can you edit this for 1hr and 5 minute timeframes